# amazon s3, adding dynamic headers to object GET by query string

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to add dynamic headers to an s3 Object by query string.
Something like

_://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myFile.png?headers=MyCustomHeader_Myvalue

---

Solved.
Found the Solution in the  [s3 Get Obejct docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html)

Using the header 
**response-content-disposition=attachment; filename='mycustomFileName'**

On the Request does the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible in S3 if you want to specify a custom value for one or more of the following:

```
Cache-Control:
Content-Type:
Content-Language:
Content-Disposition:
Content-Encoding:
Expires:
```

These response headers can actually be modified for each `GET` request by information you add to a signed query string.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

To add anything else would require a reverse proxy between the browser and S3, since S3 doesn't support dynamic modification of other response headers.